Math of Hint usage in Dilithium
For Dilithium, I understand that
$$\text{HighBits}(\mathbf{Ay}) = \text{HighBits}(\mathbf{Ay} - c\mathbf{s_2}) = \text{HighBits}(A_z - c\mathbf{t})$$
The first term of the equation is performed on the signer side while the final term is done on verifier side.
But verifier does not have access to $\mathbf{t}$ but only $\mathbf{t_1}$ calculated during key generation. So at max calculate $y = \mathbf{Az} − c\mathbf{t_1} \cdot 2^d$. To get exact $\text{Highbits}$, we also need to subtract $c\mathbf{t_0}$ from $y$.
Now, $c\mathbf{t_0}$ is limited to $\gamma2$ during signing step. So, we need to just calculate the $\text{Highbits}$ of $y$ that shall be impacted by subtracting $c\mathbf{t_0}$ from it and this is the hint (i.e. bit position at which carry occurs are 1) that signer provides encoded in the signature.
My questions are related to how the hints are used, specifically to the math of the Algorithm 34 below.

Why is the return value $\pmod m$ in the algorithm below? It also mentions $r_1$ should be max $(q-1)/2 \cdot \gamma_2$ but the same is not checked for $\text{HighBits}(\mathbf{Ay})$ in signing step.
How does $\text{LowBits}(r_0)$ play a role here ? Any example that can explain this?
Why is the $\text{MakeHint}$ calculated like this https://github.com/pq-crystals/dilithium/blob/master/ref/rounding.c#L68 ? I understand calculating $\text{HighBits}(r)$ and $\text{HighBits}(r + z)$ and then marking hintbits but the above code is unclear to me.


Algorithm 34 UseHint(h,r)
Returns the high bits of r adjusted according to hint h 
Input:boolean h, r ∈ Zq 
Output:r Z with 0 ≤ r q −1 
1 ∈ 1 ≤ 2 γ2
1: m ← (q−1)/(2γ2)
2: (r1,r0) ← Decompose(r)
3: if h = 1 and r0 > 0 return (r1 +1) mod m 
4: if h = 1 and r0 ≤ 0 return (r1 −1) mod m 
5: return r1


Please check the formatting in case I messed something up. It would be really nice if you took a bit of time and learn MathJax / Latex yourself, for instance by looking at the [edit].
